# How would I create a function that returns the next level of an array?

Tags: php

When I var_dump a variable that I have, I get the following result:

```
array(1) { [6]=> string(1) "4" }
```

I want to create a function that returns "4" in this case. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There's only one level of array here.  `$variable[6]` returns `"4"`

Comment: This is just ordinary array indexing, what's the problem?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php or https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php ???

Answer (score 0):

If the key is always an offset which you do not know, you could do [something like this](https://3v4l.org/RfN3i).

```
class ArrayHelper
{
    private array $arr = [];
    private int $count = 0;

    public function __construct(array $arr)
    {
        $this->arr = $arr;
    }
    
    public function nextValue()
    {
        # keep the keys ordered
        return $this->arr[array_keys($this->arr)[$this->count++]];
    }
}

$myArr = new ArrayHelper([6 => 4, 7 => 5, 2 => 2]);

echo $myArr->nextValue(); # 4
echo $myArr->nextValue(); # 5
echo $myArr->nextValue(); # 2
```

Or if the key doesn't matter, just use normal methods like `array_values($arr)` and/or loop through them as per normal you would any array.